# Alternative to python's .sort() (for inserting into a large list and keeping it sorted)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I need to continuously add numbers to a pre-sorted list:

```
for num in numberList:
    list.append(num)
    list.sort()
```

Each iteration is short but when the given numberList contains tens of thousands of values this method slows way down. Is there a more efficient function available that leaves a list intact and seeks out which index to insert a new number to preserve the correct order of numbers? Anything I've tried writing myself takes longer than .sort()

Comment: why are you trying to sort for each iteration? You can do that at the end of for loop is it? is that for purpose?

Comment: There's a separate part of the code after the list.sort() that runs some calculations so sorting the final list isn't an option, it has to be done for each iteration.

Comment: In general, a good practice for writing code in Python is to bind the methods in the variables outside of the loop so that the interpreter does not have to recall the `.method' with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I have a question. Does numberList change during the process or does it remain with the same data set? If the data set doesn't change, couldn't you just sort the list at the beginning, before the loop, that way you know that your numbers are sorted coming in, or do you need to know the position of the original number to begin with, which is where the sorting within the loop comes in?

Comment: @AMR I have **never** read advice about Python that you should bind instance methods to avoid the look up anywhere. It would seem to be a violation of [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). Keeping a single variable for the list is simpler and easier to understand and harder to mess up. Additionally, any overhead you incur by a method look up will be miniscule; such a change would, at best, be a premature optimization.

Comment: @jpmc26 You should probably read this then. https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Avoiding_dots...

Comment: @AMR As should you. You skipped over the "Profile if slow" part. "Choose the right data structure" is the first title suggested for optimizing, which suggests (correctly) that you should find an appropriate data structure before even considering such a change, alongside a number of other things to consider. The document itself even cautions about the danger of getting confused by such a change: "This technique should be used with caution. It gets more difficult to maintain if the loop is large." That is by *no* means "a good practice;" it's a last resort speed up.

Comment: @ jpmc26 You mean the part that says To Be Determined? Binding your methods can cut run times of a loop a considerable amount. I this example alone it was 40% savings. The other thing to remember is that Pep 8 and Pep 20 are great guidelines, but they were originally intended for the developers that participate in the open source project that is the Python Language. Pep 8 even says: "But most importantly: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply. When in doubt, use your best judgment. Look at other examples and decide what looks best. "

Comment: And you can do this: `list_append = list.append`  `list_sort = list.sort`  then `list_append(num)`   `list_sort()` and all you have done is swapped and `_` for a `.`, and you have improved run-time by 40% without substantively changed readability.

Comment: That being said, the real savings comes when you use a better method of sorting for the data set that you have. As has been shown in this post.

Comment: To answer AMR: the order of values in numberList is imperative to the functioning of the script, so your second statement of the "...need to know the position of the original number to begin with" is correct. Basically this post is to determine the fastest way to insert numbers into a new list so they are in ascending order. So far `bisect.insort()` has proven most effective but the overall code still slows dramatically when numList >> 100,000 elements.

Comment: @AMR The reason that's a bad idea is because you have to coordinate all of that state. You have multiple copies of the same thing flying around that you have to think about and manage. Assigning a *bound method* is not free. It substantially increases the cognitive load required to maintain the code, and that means it's *much* easier to introduce bugs. Many of the principles of good code have nothing to do with runtime and everything to do with how easy it is to shoot yourself in the foot. As I said before, it's a last resort performance optimization and not to be done lightly.

Comment: @AMR And if anything, the fact the "Choose the right data structure" is completely empty says *volumes* about how much you should trust that wiki. That should have been the *first* section filled in. The fact it's not means that enough care has not been given to the article.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the native bisect.insort() which implements insertion sort on lists, this should perfectly fit your needs since the [complexity is O(n) at best and O(n^2) at worst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Best.2C_worst.2C_and_average_cases) instead of O(nlogn) with your current solution (resorting after insertion).

However, there are faster alternatives to construct a sorted data structure, such as [Skip Lists](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/projects/pystyler/skiplist.py) and Binary Search Trees which will allow insertion with complexity O(log n) at best and O(n) at worst, or even better B-trees, [Red-Black trees](https://github.com/beregond/skiplist-vs-redblacktree), Splay trees and AVL trees which all have a complexity O(log n) at both best and worst cases. More infos about the complexity of all those solutions and others can be found in the great [BigO CheatSheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) by Eric Rowell. Note however that all those solutions require you to install a third-party module, and generally they need to be compiled with a C compiler.

However, there is a pure-python module called [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/), which claims to be as fast or faster than C compiled Python extensions of implementations of AVL trees and B-trees ([benchmark available here](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html)).

I benchmarked a few solutions to see which is the fastest to do an insertion sort:

```
sortedcontainers: 0.0860911591881
bisect: 0.665865982912
skiplist: 1.49330501066
sort_insert: 17.4167637739
```

Here's the code I used to benchmark:

```
from timeit import Timer
setup = """
L = list(range(10000)) + list(range(10100, 30000))
from bisect import insort

def sort_insert(L, x):
    L.append(x)
    L.sort()

from lib.skiplist import SkipList
L2 = SkipList(allowDups=1)
for x in L:
    L2.insert(x)

from lib.sortedcontainers import SortedList
L3 = SortedList(L)
"""

# Using sortedcontainers.SortedList()
t_sortedcontainers = Timer("for i in xrange(10000, 10100): L3.add(i)", setup)
# Using bisect.insort()
t_bisect = Timer("for i in xrange(10000, 10100): insort(L, i)", setup)
# Using a Skip List
t_skiplist = Timer("for i in xrange(10000, 10100): L2.insert(i)", setup)
# Using a standard list insert and then sorting
t_sort_insert = Timer("for i in xrange(10000, 10100): sort_insert(L, i)", setup)

# Timing the results
print t_sortedcontainers.timeit(number=100)
print t_bisect.timeit(number=100)
print t_skiplist.timeit(number=100)
print t_sort_insert.timeit(number=100)
```

So the results indicate that the **sortedcontainers is indeed almost 7x faster than bisect** (and I expect the speed gap to increase with the list size since the complexity is an order of magnitude different).

What's more surprising is that the skip list is slower than bisect, but it's probably because it's not as optimized as bisect, which is implemented in C and may use some optimization tricks (note that the skiplist.py module I used was the fastest pure-Python Skip List I could find, the [pyskip module](https://github.com/toastdriven/pyskip) being a lot slower).

Also worth of note: if you need to use more complex structures than lists, the sortedcontainers module offers SortedList, SortedListWithKey, SortedDict and SortedSet (while bisect only works on lists). Also, you might be interested by this [somewhat related benchmark](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/305779-sorting-part2-some-performance-considerations/) and this [complexity cheatsheet of various Python operations](https://github.com/zanqi/python-complexity).

Comment: "complexity is O(log n)" - why? O(log n) is for finding the place to insert, but for inserting you still need O(n)

Comment: Inserting in a python's list using bisect seems to be done in constant time O(1), so once the index to insert sort is found,  there is no additional cost

Comment: "Inserting in a python's list using bisect seems to be done in constant time O(1)" - it's impossible, dude. Python's list is an array, not linked list.

Comment: @SmitJohnth you're right, the mailing list where I've read that was wrong (or partially correct): only finding the correct index by bisection is in O(log n), for insertion sort it's O(n) at best and O(n^2) at worst. I've updated my answer, thank's.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [`bisect.insort()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort) to insert values into an already sorted list:

```
from bisect import insort

insort(list, num)
```

Note that this'll still take some time as the remaining elements after the insertion point all have to be shifted up a step; you may want to think about re-implementing the list as a linked list instead.

However, if you are keeping the list sorted just to always be able to get the smallest or largest number, you should use the [`heapq` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) instead; a heap is not kept in strict sorted order, but is very efficient at giving you the either the smallest or largest value very quickly, at all times.

Comment: This is the analysis of the performance enhancement. Run on a list of `100,000` randomly generated integers.`Time for insort 1.649233102798462` 
`Time for list_append and list_sort 344.4988350868225` 
`Time for list.append and list.sort 559.2065420150757`

Comment: What about trees? It's been a while since I needed them, but don't they provide reasonable time for access, insertion, and deletion even when sorted?

Comment: A binary search tree can work too, yes, depending on the use cases.

Comment: AFAIK Search trees are not natively implemented in python so using them implies using a third party module which may incur a performance cost since they are more complex data structures, while bisect works with the same complexity on simple lists. A good middle ground can be using skip lists which are way simpler than binary search trees bit still less than lists.

Comment: Linked lists and skip lists are not part of the standard library either. Using a third party library does in no way imply that they are slower.

Comment: If you really need a tree, you probably have enough data that you actually need an in-memory SQLite database, which will conveniently do all the tree stuff for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did say it "may" incur a performance cost, it depends on the implementation. Bisect is part of the native lib so it's well tested and (normally) optimized. But of course, third party modules can be faster if well implemented and particularly if the complexity is on another order of magnitude.